1-norm of projector matrix
Let $\mathbb R^{d\times k}$. It is well-known that the orthogonal projection operator over the column space of this matrix is given by
$$Px=A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top x.$$
Indeed, the 2-norm of this operator is $1$. What about the $\infty-$norm, given by
$$\sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1}\|Px\|_{\infty}?$$
Can we bound it as a function of $d,k$?
My thoughts
As the set $\|x\|_\infty=1$ is contained in $\|x\|_2\le \sqrt d$ and $\|Px\|_{\infty}\le \|Px\|_{2}$, we have
$$\sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1}\|Px\|_{\infty}\le \sup_{\|x\|_2\le \sqrt d}\|Px\|_{2}=\sqrt d.$$
Still, I fear this factor $\sqrt d$ is not tight. Sampling $50.000$ random matrices for $d=20,k=40$ only gives, as maximum, $\approx 2.82$. If we increase the dimension at $d=100,k=50$, for $5000$ iteration (the computation starts becoming long) we get $\approx 2.66$. So, I would guess that the growth in $d$ is at most logarithmic.

I think it would be a good starting point to get a handle on the case of $k = 1$. That is, strictly consider the case where $P = vv^\top$, where $|v|_2 = 1$
